# Why is $\int f_n\, d\mu\nearrow\sup_n\int f_n\, d\mu$?

Tags: measure-theory

> > Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a measure space and $f_n,f$ non-negative, measurable, numeric functions.

In a proof of the statement that from $0\leq f_n\nearrow f$ it follows that $\int f_n\, d\mu\nearrow\int f\, d\mu$ I've found the claim that
$$
0\leq\int f_n\, d\mu\nearrow\sup_n\int f_n\, d\mu\leq\int f\, d\mu.
$$
I cannot see why 
$$
\int f_n\, d\mu\nearrow\sup_n\int f_n\, d\mu.
$$

---

Because from $0\leq f_n$ and $f_n\to f$ it follows 
$$
0\leq\int f_n\, d\mu\leq\int f_{n+1}\, d\mu.
$$
But why $\nearrow\sup_n\int f_n\, d\mu$?

---

**Edit**: In general it is:

If $(a_n)$ is an increasing sequence of numbers then of course this sequence is limited by its supremum. And then it is $a:=\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=\sup_n a_n =:s$.

*Suppose that $a\neq s$*. Then $s<a$ or $s>a$.

(I.) $s<a$: Let $\varepsilon >0 $ be arbitrary. Then there exists a $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ so that for $n>n_0$ big enough it is $a_n>s$. Thats a contradiction, because $s$ is the supremum and so $a_n\leq s$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

(II.) $s>a$: Then $s$ is not the sumpremum, because for example define $t:=a+\frac{s-a}{2}$. It is $a_n\leq t<s~\forall~n\in\mathbb{N}$.

So it has to be $s=a$.

Applied on the problem above:

By assumption it is $f_n\nearrow f$, i.e. $f_n\leq f_{n+1}$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n=f=\sup_n f_n$.

So it follows by monotony of the integral:

$$
\int f_n\, d\mu\leq\int f_{n+1}\, d\mu.
$$
Moreover the seuqnce of the integrals is limited by
$$
\sup_n\int f_n\, d\mu.
$$
So by the general statement above it follows that
$$
\int f_n\, d\mu\nearrow \lim_n\int f_n\, d\mu=\sup_n\int f_n\, d\mu.
$$

Hoe its correct now.

Answer (score 5):

Any increasing sequence of numbers converges to its supremum.

Comment: Ok, I've tried to prove that. I add this to my question.

Comment: Your argument is not entirely correct, because a priori you don't know that the limit exists. What you know is that either the sequence is unboudned, or it has a finite supremum. In this latter case you can show that the supremum is the limit. In the first case, both limit and supremum are infinite.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this symbol $f_n\nearrow f$ means that $f_n$ is increasing.

IF this is the case then what you want to show is simply the [Monotone Convergence Theorem.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem)